In Unity engine, why are Quaternion & Euler angles uses different Chirality?
I experimented with a simple Unity program with 1 camera, with a tracked pose driver. The result looks like this:
When given a Euler angle of XYZ format:

pitch up <=> X decrease
pitch down <=> X increase
yaw right <=> Y increase
yaw left <=> Y decrease
roll clockwise <=> Z decrease
roll counter-clockwise <=> Z increase

all evidences seems to indicate that Unity Euler angle uses a LDB (left-down-back) coordinate system, with both right-hand rotation and right-hand axes order.
However, when dealing with quaternion, many documents imply that a left-hand system was used.
Are these documents stating the truth? If so, this will cause a lot of trouble in conversion between different protocol. What's the purpose of this divergence?

There is a 12 ways to apply Euler Angels. Few chances to fit exactly your expectation.

lol evidently there are more (6 sequences * 2 chiralities * XYX/XYZ)

Unity uses left-handed coordinates, with Y up.
It applies euler angle rotations "sequentially around the z-axis, the x-axis and then the y-axis".
This image is from the documentation:

This is left-handed because pairing the x with your thumb, the y with your index finger, and the z of this diagram with your middle finger is only possible using your left hand and is impossible with your right hand. Again, as per the diagram, positive (angle increasing) rotation happens along an axis counterclockwise as you face the positive direction of the axis, counterclockwise as you face the negative direction of the axis.
I don't really understand what you are doing to convert this to LDB as I'm not familiar with the notation, but if coordinates are left hand and rotation order is also applied on a left-hand coordinate, I don't see there being any conversion problems.
Read more in the docs..

Z, X, Y axis refers to right, back, up, if you invert them and remap you get LDB coordinate system, which is still right-handed (unless you use left hand to represent rotation, which never happens)

I don't think I understand the problem you are having. What issues is this causing for you? What are you trying to do?

Z X Y are referring to a left hand system in this rotation. there's a diagram. I don't follow how this is equivalent to a right hand system.

the convention for representing rotation direction is by aligning thumb with axis and wrapped finger will align with rotation direction, with the right hand. Do you have the diagram?

@tribbloid that's true for right hand coordinate systems... but in left hand systems you do this with the left hand, yeah?

if I use left hand to represent both axis sequence and rotation-to-axis relationship, I end up getting the same system :D

Cool, I'm sorry but what's the problem then?

Added more context to my answer. Please let me know if you are still having issues.

answer looks good, the problem is that you can call the same system left-handed or right-handed, and some other systems neither, which is absurd. We need a better terminology
